# Prevent Unity Editor application from entering play mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to prevent Unity from changing the playmode after the user has pressed the button?

Let's say I have a custom editor which may have a state which can't be properly serialized; if user changes Unity Editor mode at this moment, their changes will be lost.

It is an option to completely get rid of non-serializeable state, but this is the task of completely different complexity. Would like to avoid that.

**UPD:**

I've tested  [derHugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53925187/3391586) with the following script:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Innoactive.Hub.Training.Editors
{
    [InitializeOnLoad]
    public class ProveThatDudeWrongWindow : EditorWindow
    {
        private static ProveThatDudeWrongWindow windowInstance;

        private string notSerializedString = "default";

        static ProveThatDudeWrongWindow()
        {
            EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += OnPlayModeStateChanged;
        }

        [MenuItem("Test/I'm damn sure he's wrong")]
        private static void MenuItem()
        {
            if (windowInstance == null)
            {
                windowInstance = GetWindow<ProveThatDudeWrongWindow>();
            }

            windowInstance.notSerializedString = "some value";
        }

        [MenuItem("Test/Display current value")]
        private static void DisplayCurrentNonSerializedValue()
        {
            windowInstance = GetWindow<ProveThatDudeWrongWindow>();
            Debug.Log("string: " + windowInstance.notSerializedString);
        }

        private static void OnPlayModeStateChanged(PlayModeStateChange state)
        {
            if (state == PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode)
            {
                EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
            }

            Debug.Log("state: " + state);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I've done the following:

1. Press `Test/I'm damn sure he's wrong` option to set non-serialized value from `default` value to `some value`
2. Press `Test/Display current value` to make sure the value is changed
3. Press play button
4. Press `Test/Display current value` to see current value. If it is `default`, derHugo's solution does not work, if it is `some value`, it works.

Result: derHugo is cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is I think

You can register to [`EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-playModeStateChanged.html)

Look at the example from the doc I modified:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public static class PlayModeStateChangedExample
{   
    private static void LogPlayModeState(PlayModeStateChange state)
    {
        Debug.Log(state);
    }

    public static void SetPlayModeEnabled(bool enabled)
    {
        //This is possible since you allways can remove
        //a listener even if there is none so far
        //This allways removes the listener making sure it is only added once  
          EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged -= LogPlayModeState;

        if(!enabled)
        {
            EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += LogPlayModeState;
        }
    }
}
```

Now all that's left is resetting [`EditorApplication.isPlaying`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-isPlaying.html) back to `false` e.g. by replacing

```
Debug.Log(state);
```

with

```
// This mode occures right before entering PlayMode
// and is the moment in which we want to intervene
if(state == PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode)
{
    EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
}
```

to kill the PlayMode.

So you can call from anywhere e.g.

```
PlayModeStateChangedExample.SetPlayModeEnabled(false);
```

---

I'm not sure however if this would completely prevent the serialization part since it also states in the doc

> Setting `isPlaying` delays the result until after all script code has completed for this frame.

Comment: (I was expecting it to enter the play mode and immediately leave it, but it actually prevents it in the first place).

Comment: Glad to help! To be honest I shared your doubts a bit as well ^^